# QGIS Crashes exporting from print layout

Tags: qgis, print-composer, printing

So im trying to export my map layout to PDF and no matter what options i select QGIS just closes without warning while it is supposedly exporting.

Ive tried with PDF, IMG, TIFF and they all do the same. Ideally im exporting to ARCH E size page, but even if i try A4 page size it still crashes.

My project file is fairly large with a lot of layers, but i imagine its not more than a lot of projects that get made.

Ive seen theres a bug that causes this issue if you have label masking enabled but i dont have any labels and still having this issue.
any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean by _fairly large project _? Which version of QGIS are you using? Can you share a link showing this bug are you mentioning? Because I'm using version 3.28.11 and I can export maps, as PNGs usually but with 1500 dpi, without an issue.

Comment: Is this project the only one that causes problems; others work fine?  If they all crash reinstall and/or delete and rebuild you QGIS app data folder.  If they work fine focus on the layers in your project.  You could check their geometry.  If any are internet service based turn them off and try.  If you turn off  other layers does it still crash?

Comment: My project folder is about 8 GB of file> couple hundred layers
Im using 3.22

Small projects export fine but i have 2 different version of this project and both close while exporting. Even when exporting at only 100DPI
There are no online layers.

How would i rebuild the qgis app data folder? Where is that?
Is there a certain layer geometry issue that this happens with?

Comment: Im trying to export at Arch E page size but cant seem to get it to export above Arch C page size at 300 DPI.

is this just a Ram issue? I have 16GB ram.